# How can I (reproducible) trigger an EIO error from close(2)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

The Linux man page of `close(2)` states:

> ### NOTES
>
> Not checking the return value of `close()` is a common but nevertheless serious programming error. It is quite possible that error on a previous `write(2)` operation are first reported at the final `close()`. Not checking the return value when closing the file may lead to silent loss of data. This can especially be observed with NFS and with disk quota. [...]

Now I was wondering whether this is actually true: Lots of software projects *do not* check the return value of `close()`, but is that a problem? I tried to generate such an error by using small `ext2` file systems in files, and writing to files near the boundary of the disk capacity, but the only thing I'd get was `ENOSPC` from the `write(2)` system call.

So: Is there a way to reproducibly trigger an I/O error on `close(2)` with a valid file descriptor referring to a **file**, preferrably on Linux, but *BSD would be fine as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the manpage states, this is mainly a problem with NFS shares. Quoting nfs.sourceforge.net:

> So, when an application opens a file stored in NFS, the NFS client checks that it still exists on the server, and is permitted to the opener, by sending a GETATTR or ACCESS operation. When the application closes the file, the NFS client writes back any pending changes to the file so that the next opener can view the changes. This also gives the NFS client an opportunity to report any server write errors to the application via the return code from close().

That is where checking the ret value of close() becomes important. On-disk filesystems would not give EIO under normal circumstances when you close(fd). But you could try things like pulling out that USB stick just when your program closes the filedes.

Answer (score 1):

Since an NFS share might not be as reproducible of a test case as you might be looking for, you could also use a custom FUSE filesystem that returns EIO consistently.

Based on [this example](https://pythonhosted.org/llfuse/example.html#single-file-read-only-file-system) from python-llfuse, here's how you might be able to do this:

```
# See header in original example for a copy of the MIT license
import os, sys, stat, errno, llfuse, time
class TestFs(llfuse.Operations):
    now = time.time()
    name = b"file"
    data = b"text\n"
    fino = llfuse.ROOT_INODE + 1
    def getattr(self, inode, ctx=None):
        entry = llfuse.EntryAttributes()
        if inode == llfuse.ROOT_INODE:
            entry.st_mode, entry.st_size = (stat.S_IFDIR | 0o755), 0
        elif inode == self.fino:
            entry.st_mode, entry.st_size = (stat.S_IFREG | 0o644), len(self.data)
        else:
            raise llfuse.FUSEError(errno.ENOENT)
        entry.st_atime_ns = entry.st_ctime_ns = entry.st_mtime_ns = self.now
        entry.st_gid, entry.st_uid = os.getgid(), os.getuid()
        entry.st_ino = inode
        return entry
    def setattr(self, inode, attr, fields, fh, ctx):
        return self.getattr(inode) # ignore it
    def lookup(self, parent_inode, name, ctx=None):
        if parent_inode != llfuse.ROOT_INODE or name != self.name:
            raise llfuse.FUSEError(errno.ENOENT)
        return self.getattr(self.fino)
    def opendir(self, inode, ctx):
        if inode != llfuse.ROOT_INODE:
            raise llfuse.FUSEError(errno.ENOENT)
        return inode
    def readdir(self, fh, off):
        assert fh == llfuse.ROOT_INODE
        if off == 0:
            yield (self.name, self.getattr(self.fino), 1)
    def open(self, inode, flags, ctx):
        if inode != self.fino:
            raise llfuse.FUSEError(errno.ENOENT)
        return inode
    def read(self, fh, off, size):
        return self.data[off:off+size]
    def write(self, fh, off, buf):
        return len(buf)
    def flush(self, fh):
        raise llfuse.FUSEError(errno.EIO)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    testfs = TestFs()
    llfuse.init(testfs, "/tmp/mp")
    try:
        llfuse.main(workers=1)
    finally:
        llfuse.close()
```

Now, let's try it:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/mp
$ python example.py &
$ ls /tmp/mp
file
$ cat /tmp/mp/file
text
cat: /tmp/mp/file: Input/output error
$ cat /dev/null >/tmp/mp/file
cat: write error: Input/output error
```

To explain how this example works: it's essentially just a bunch of stub implementations, except for these two lines:

```
def flush(self, fh):
    raise llfuse.FUSEError(errno.EIO)
```

`flush` is called whenever a flush or close operation occurs - and we just raise EIO, which means that, whenever someone flushes or closes this file, the syscall will return -EIO. You'll probably want to tweak this program a bit, but it should provide a very reproducible way to test the behavior of a program when encountering EIO.